# jQuery: Scrolling like a contained ios scrolling box you would see in the app store

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Here is what I am talking about:

When you visit https://soundcloud.com/ , when you look at the homepage you see the whole "Connect on Soundcloud" thing.

The texts and buttons on the screen in that confined space scrolls by itself in a given amount of time. It also has those two small white circle buttons that tell you which item it is on(the first white circle gets filled in while the other one is hollowed out with a border when the user is looking at "Connect on SoundCloud" and the other way around when it is on "Discover more with SoundCloud GO+").

How is this made?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called **carousel**, and it is part of many frameworks/libraries like [Bootstap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/). Some frameworks/libraries call it **gallery**.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Carousels](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) on w3schools, they cover this pretty well.

Bootstrap brings functions and html attributes for building components that slide though elements. Elements not currently visible are pushed off the view with CSS and visible ones can slide into view.